# How can I get response from http url by axios (or request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, request

I am trying to fetch data from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) by axios and request. I found that when I pass 'http' url to axios, it returned 'Network Error'.

code

```
import axios from "axios"
const url='http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
axios.get(url)
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

response

```
AxiosError: Network Error
  message: "Network Error"
  name: "AxiosError"
  code: "ERR_NETWORK"
  config: (15) {transitional: {...}, adapter: xhrAd...}
  request: XMLHttpRequest {data: undefined}
  response: XMLHttpRequest {data: undefined}
```

Or you can see all responses I have tried in these images.

- [Axios with http url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3qZn.png)
- [Axios with https url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3tT6.png)
- [Request with http url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRb6R.png)
- [Request with https url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlWUG.png)
- [and this image use python requests to confirm that this API can be called by using both http and https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDQu0.png)

How can I get response from http url by [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) (or [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request))?

Comment: are you making http request in nodejs or a browser?

Comment: I'm using nodejs and test code on playcode.io

Comment: This looks like an issue with playcode.io. I can't reproduce it when I use a local copy of Node.js.

Comment: playcode is a webapp, hosted over HTTPs, then all external resources it is consuming (CDN, scripts, CSS files, API calls) should also use SSL and be secured through HTTPs.
Thats why you're not able to make "http" url requests on playcode

[Read MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests)

Comment: Thank you so much. I never knew that using playcode would cause this problem . I would test code on my local machine from now on.

Answer (score -1):

It takes some time for the request to return. Hence you must call it asynchronously:

```
async function getSomeDataWithAsync() {
  /*
    Using await inside a function marked as async tells the browser to HOLD UP
    on running any more of the functions code until the promise is returned and the 
    value is set in the response variable.
  */
    const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  /*
    This is the same exact point as the first .then in the getSomeData function above 
    this one.  You can see async/await is slightly less verbose.
  */
  console.log(response)
  
  /*
    At this point you can extract the data from the resolved promise
    and use it.
  */
  const { data } = response;
  console.log(data);
}

getSomeDataWithAsync();
```

Comment: But already promise is being used.

Comment: You are right, sorry. Strange however that the async / await approach works where as promise does not.

Comment: Promise also works, the user who asked the question was using a web app deployed on https to run the axios request. 
The browser blocks the requests made on http urls if the site from which you're making request is hosted on https.

If you make http request using promise in local environment it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the inside :-) How could I miss that....